# BTC-E ticker time format

Tags: python, json, types, pandas, format

Im using python to pull the Bitcoin ticker into a pandas DF and put into my SQL Database, however I have no idea what format the dam servertime and updated times are in. I would like to convert the the time in my pandas DF first then put into my SQL DB.

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://@localhost")

bitcoin = 'https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker'
data = urllib.urlopen(bitcoin)
data = json.load(data)
data = json_normalize(data)

data = pd.DataFrame(data)

data.to_sql('TESTTABLE',engine, if_exists='append', index = False)

print data
```

For now the servertime and updated information is going into columns in my SQL DB that are set to bigint datatype.

Anyhelp would be awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Right now pandas is bringing both times in as int64.  Changing them is relatively easy with pd.to_datetime() once you figure out the format (sorry, can't help you there).   to_datetime() will change the data type and parse the date based on the format parameter.  For example

```
data['ticker.server_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['ticker.server_time'],
format='whatever is needed')
```

format : string, default None
    strftime to parse time, eg "%d/%m/%Y", note that "%f" will parse
    all the way up to nanoseconds

I tried using the infer_datetime_format parameter with that data, but it didn't make a difference.

```
data['ticker.server_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['ticker.server_time'],
infer_datetime_format=True)`
```